# Value of type 'UICollectionViewCell?' has no member 'contentImage'

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have two custom UICollectionViewCells(`AddImageCollectionViewCell`, `ItemCollectionViewCell`) which I am loading depending on indexpath. Here is my code for the `cellForItemAtIndexpath`-

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        var cell :UICollectionViewCell!

        if indexPath.row == 0{
            cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "addImageCell", for: indexPath) as! AddImageCollectionViewCell
        }
        else{
             cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ItemCell", for: indexPath) as! ItemCollectionViewCell
            cell.contentImage = self.droppedItemList[indexPath.row] //error here
        }
        return cell
    }
```

I am getting the error as "Value of type 'UICollectionViewCell?' has no member 'contentImage'". Why is my cell in the else clause is not cast to "ItemCollectionViewCell" type.

I know, I must be doing something very foolish. I would be really grateful if someone can point me to the right direction.

Comment: Any ideas why this was voted down? I'm still learning the culture here.

Comment: May be the issue was really silly or may be I haven't phrased the title of the issue properly. It's fine as long as I get response. Regarding the culture, as far as I know, if no one else have queried anything related to your one and you clearly address your problem with the attempted code, your query won't be downvoted.

Comment: Thank-you Natasha for your informative point of view on this. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring `cell` as basic type `UICollectionViewCell`, that's the reason. Return the cells separately

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "addImageCell", for: indexPath) as! AddImageCollectionViewCell
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ItemCell", for: indexPath) as! ItemCollectionViewCell
        cell.contentImage = self.droppedItemList[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick fix. I knew, I did something really stupid.